# Pydantic: Create model with fixed and extended fields from a Dict[str, OtherModel], the Typescript [key: string] way

Tags: python, typescript, class, pydantic

From a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70888691/6225838), the goal is to create a model like this Typescript interface:

```
interface ExpandedModel {
  fixed: number;
  [key: string]: OtherModel;
}
```

However the **OtherModel** needs to be validated, so simply using:

```
class ExpandedModel(BaseModel):
    fixed: int

    class Config:
        extra = "allow"
```

Won't be enough. I tried [**root** (pydantic docs)](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/models/#custom-root-types):

```
class VariableKeysModel(BaseModel):
    __root__: Dict[str, OtherModel]
```

But doing something like:

```
class ExpandedModel(VariableKeysModel):
    fixed: int
```

Is not possible due to:

> ValueError: **root** cannot be mixed with other fields

Would something like [`@root_validator` (example from another answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69907165/6225838) be helpful in this case?

Comment: Are you sure this is not an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info)? Can you explain, what the purpose of such a model would be? Because it is certainly possible, it just seems like trying to hammer in a screw. The beauty of class-based models is that the type safety that comes with fixed defined attributes. If you are dealing with dynamic key-object-pairs, why not just use a dynamic data structure like a `dict` and validate each item separately? Where is your data coming from and what do you intend to do with it?

Comment: I agree it's not pretty. I'm using Pydantic to parse all models from a file and this is just one of those that need to be validated properly. I don't agree with the [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) assessment though: this kind of interface is common in TS, it should be simple to replicate in pydantic (e.g. class inheritance) and others have asked for similar solutions…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thankfully, Python is *not* TypeScript. As mentioned in the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75500948) as well, an object is generally not a dictionary and dynamic attributes are considered bad form in almost all cases.

You can of course still set attributes dynamically, but they will for example never be recognized by a static type checker like Mypy or your IDE. This means you will not get auto-suggestions for those dynamic fields. Only attributes that are statically defined within the namespace of the class are considered members of that class.

That being said, you can abuse the [`extra`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/model_config/) config option to allow arbitrary fields to by dynamically added to the model, while at the same time enforcing all corresponding values to be of a specific type via a [`root_validator`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/validators/#root-validators).

```py
from typing import Any

from pydantic import BaseModel, root_validator


class Foo(BaseModel):
    a: int


class Bar(BaseModel):
    b: str

    @root_validator
    def validate_foo(cls, values: dict[str, Any]) -> dict[str, Any]:
        for name, value in values.items():
            if name in cls.__fields__:
                continue  # ignore statically defined fields here
            values[name] = Foo.parse_obj(value)
        return values

    class Config:
        extra = "allow"
```

Demo:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from pydantic import ValidationError

    bar = Bar.parse_obj({
        "b": "xyz",
        "foo1": {"a": 1},
        "foo2": Foo(a=2),
    })
    print(bar.json(indent=4))

    try:
        Bar.parse_obj({
            "b": "xyz",
            "foo": {"a": "string"},
        })
    except ValidationError as err:
        print(err.json(indent=4))

    try:
        Bar.parse_obj({
            "b": "xyz",
            "foo": {"not_a_foo_field": 1},
        })
    except ValidationError as err:
        print(err.json(indent=4))
```

Output:

```json
{
    "b": "xyz",
    "foo2": {
        "a": 2
    },
    "foo1": {
        "a": 1
    }
}
```

```json
[
    {
        "loc": [
            "__root__",
            "a"
        ],
        "msg": "value is not a valid integer",
        "type": "type_error.integer"
    }
]
```

```json
[
    {
        "loc": [
            "__root__",
            "a"
        ],
        "msg": "field required",
        "type": "value_error.missing"
    }
]
```

---

A *better* approach IMO is to just put the dynamic name-object-pairs into a dictionary. For example, you could define a separate field `foos: dict[str, Foo]` on the `Bar` model and get automatic validation out of the box that way.

Or you ditch the outer base model altogether for that specific case and just handle the data as a native dictionary with `Foo` values and parse them all via the `Foo` model.

Comment: Appreciate all details and suggestions you provided, a minor alternative to avoid the **Config** in the _Bar_ model would be to declare `class Bar(BaseModel, extra=Extra.allow):`.

Comment: @CPHPython Yes, you can always pass your config as `__init_subclass__` keword-arguments. What is more readable/usable, depends on the situation and personal preference of course.