# Python arbritary keys in TypedDict

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing, typeddict

Is it possible to make a TypedDict with a set of known keys and then a type for an arbitrary key? For example, in TypeScript, I could do this:

```
interface Sample {
  x: boolean;
  y: number;

  [name: string]: string;
}
```

What is the equivalent in Python?

---

Edit: My problem is that I make a library where a function's argument expects a type of `Mapping[str, SomeCustomClass]`. I want to change the type so that there are now special keys, where the types are like this:

- `labels: Mapping[str, str]`
- `aliases: Mapping[str, List[str]]`

But I want it to still be an arbitrary mapping where if a key is not in the two special cases above, it should be of type `SomeCustomClass`. What is a good way to do this? I am not interested in making a backwards-incompatible change if there is an alternative.

Comment: Fortunately, Python is not TypeScript. There's no such construct in python - usually no one needs it, because dicts are not objects, and I'd put this "rest" into separate key (`x: int; y: int; extra: dict[str, str]`) to reduce namespace polllusion and just improve readability. Then you can keep using a TypedDict or define a normal class. Also, a class with custom `__getattr__` would be the closest possible equivalent, I guess - you can always convert it to dict manually later.

Comment: @SUTerliakov the thing is that I already have a method that takes a dictionary where the keys are all prefixed with "P" and have a certain output type. But I want to make it possible to add some other keys without the prefix and with a different type. It seems to not be possible.

Comment: [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info) alert! Please edit your post and provide additional context: Why do you think such a construct would be useful? What problem would it solve? Otherwise I agree with @SUTerliakov

Comment: A not so shameless plug: thank you Daniil for your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75507540/6225838) detailing how to address this.

Answer (score 1):

That is possible with Union type operator, but unfortunately with this solution, you lose checking the required fields:

```
from typing import TypedDict, Union, Dict

class SampleRequiredType(TypedDict, total=True):
  x: bool
  y: int

SampleType = Union[SampleRequiredType, Dict]

# Now all these dictionaries will be valid:

dict1: SampleType = {
  'x': True,
  'y': 123
}

dict2: SampleType = {
  'x': True,
  'y': 123
  'z': 'my string' 
}

dict3: SampleType = {
  'z': 'my string' 
}
```